# Can I serialize/deserialize System Types to XML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, serialization

I want to save my models as individual XML files that people can load, save and import.
Can I serialize/deserialize System types like Enums and System.Windows.Media.Color to XML files?

```
 public enum WeatherType
 {
    Rainy,
    Sunny,
    Cloudy,
    Windy
 }

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Profile")]
public class Profile
{
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.Color ProfileColor { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public double MinTemp { get; set; }
    public double MaxTemp { get; set; }
    public List<WeatherType> WeatherTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Can't seem to make it work :/

Comment: Enums are serializable by definition. `Color` seems to be serializable too. What's the problem?

Comment: What's not working? Can you post code where you facing issue?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is. Can you give some more info.

Here is a sample code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Profile p = new Profile();
    p.ProfileColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(1, 1, 1, 0);
    p.WeatherTypes = new List<WeatherType>
        {
            WeatherType.Cloudy,
            WeatherType.Windy
        };
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Profile));
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, p);
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

and here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Profile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ProfileColor>
    <A>1</A>
    <R>1</R>
    <G>1</G>
    <B>0</B>
    <ScA>0.003921569</ScA>
    <ScR>0.000303527</ScR>
    <ScG>0.000303527</ScG>
    <ScB>0</ScB>
  </ProfileColor>
  <MinTemp>0</MinTemp>
  <MaxTemp>0</MaxTemp>
  <WeatherTypes>
    <WeatherType>Cloudy</WeatherType>
    <WeatherType>Windy</WeatherType>
  </WeatherTypes>
</Profile>
```

Answer (score 1):

`enum` and `Color` are serializable by definition (decorated with the `SerializableAttribute`) so there shouldn't be any problems serializing `enum` or `Color` properties, look at my code example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))
        {
            var telAvivProfile = new Profile
                {
                    City = "Tel Aviv",
                    MaxTemp = 40,
                    MinTemp = 5,
                    ProfileColor = Color.FromRgb(4, 4, 4),
                    WeatherTypes = new List<WeatherType>
                        {
                            WeatherType.Sunny,
                            WeatherType.Rainy
                        }
                };

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(telAvivProfile.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(writer, telAvivProfile);

            Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public enum WeatherType
{
    Rainy,
    Sunny,
    Cloudy,
    Windy
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Profile")]
public class Profile
{
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.Color ProfileColor { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public double MinTemp { get; set; }
    public double MaxTemp { get; set; }
    public List<WeatherType> WeatherTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Will produce you the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ProfileColor="">
    <A>255</A>
    <R>4</R>
    <G>4</G>
    <B>4</B>
    <ScA>1</ScA>
    <ScR>0.001214108</ScR>
    <ScG>0.001214108</ScG>
    <ScB>0.001214108</ScB>
    </ProfileColor>
    <City>Tel Aviv</City>
    <MinTemp>5</MinTemp>
    <MaxTemp>45</MaxTemp>
    <WeatherTypes>
      <WeatherType>Sunny</WeatherType>
      <WeatherType>Rainy</WeatherType>
    </WeatherTypes>
</Profile>
```

In addition, if you want control over how your `enum` fields are serialized out then you can decorate each field with the `XmlEnum` attribute, for example:

```
public enum WeatherType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name="Hot")]
    Rainy,
    Sunny,
    Cloudy,
    Windy
}
```

And here is how you can Deserialize/Load your XML from a file:

```
    Profile loadedProfile = null;
    string path = "telAvivProfile.xml";

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Profile));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    loadedProfile = (Profile) serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    reader.Close();
```